# Validate FIXML against Schema (XSD)

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I'm trying to validate some FIXML messages that I received from a business partner but I couldn't. I think should be a namespace problem because the parser don't identify the root tag (FIXML). Any thoughts?

Thanks a lot for any help.

**Java Schema Validator**

```
static boolean validateAgainstXSD(InputStream xml, InputStream xsd) {
        try {
            SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
            Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new StreamSource(xsd));
            Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
            validator.validate(new StreamSource(xml));
            return true;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

**FIXML to be validated**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FIXML v="FIX.5.0SP2" xmlns:xs="http://www.fixprotocol.org/FIXML-5-0-SP2">
    <TrdCaptRpt TrdID="32KGWND0000000099@20220411" ExecID="ExecID" TrdDt="2022-04-11" BizDt="2022-04-11" LastUpdateTm="2022-04-11T09:27:23.404Z" LastQty="1" LastPx="101.1" MktSegID="XEUR" LastMkt="XEUR" VenuTyp="E" TrdTyp="0" AsOfInd="0" TransTyp="0" MtchID="1" TrnsfrRsn="004" MLegRptTyp="1" Clrd="0">
        <Hdr SeqNum="2587905699377885" SID="CM1_EU" TID="CM1_EU" Snt="2022-04-11T14:14:59.407564Z" SSub="FIS CD"/>
        <RegTrdID Evnt="2" Typ="0" ID="E01XEURECAGWC00000000000099KGWND0000000002"/>
        <Instrmt Exch="XEUR" Sym="DBK9" CFI="OCXXXN" MatDt="2023-03-31" MMY="202303" PutCall="1" StrkPx="100.0"/>
        <RptSide Side="1" TrdID="32KGWND0000000099" PosEfct="O" CustOrdHdlInst="D">
            <Pty ID="CM1_EU" R="1"/>
            <Pty ID="CLIENT1UK_ACC1_DEFACCREF" R="24"/>
            <Pty ID="A1" R="38"/>
            <Pty ID="CM1_EU" R="4"/>
            <Pty ID="ECAG" R="21"/>
            <Pty ID="TRADER" R="12"/>
            <TrdRegTS TS="2022-04-11T08:18:03.689Z" Typ="1"/>
            <TrdRegTS TS="2022-04-11T14:14:59.391Z" Typ="13"/>
            <TrdRegTS TS="2022-04-11T08:18:03.689Z" Typ="19"/>
            <TrdRptOrdDetl OrdID="ORDERID"/>
        </RptSide>
    </TrdCaptRpt>
</FIXML>
```

**XML Schema to validate**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!-- FIXML Schema Version FIX.5.0SP2 EP240 Generated: 2017-12-29T02:42:44.519Z 
    Copyright(c) FIX Protocol Limited. All rights reserved. Comments and errors 
    should be posted on the FIX protocol web-site http://www.fixtradingcommunity.org -->

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns="http://www.fixprotocol.org/FIXML-5-0-SP2"
           xmlns:fm="http://www.fixprotocol.org/FIXML-5-0-SP2/METADATA"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.fixprotocol.org/FIXML-5-0-SP2/METADATA fixml-metadata-5-0-SP2.xsd"
           targetNamespace="http://www.fixprotocol.org/FIXML-5-0-SP2"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
   <xs:include schemaLocation="fixml-tradecapture-base-5-0-SP2.xsd"/>
</xs:schema>
```

**PS:** All included schemas are available in the same folder where the referenced is, as you can see below.

[Schemas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSn8w.png)

Comment: When you say you "couldn't validate the XML", what you mean is that you successfully ran a validation that showed the XML to be invalid - which is precisely what validation is supposed to do.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the XML:

```
<FIXML v="FIX.5.0SP2" xmlns:xs="http://www.fixprotocol.org/FIXML-5-0-SP2">
```

This assigns alias `xs` to the namespace `http://www.fixprotocol.org/FIXML-5-0-SP2` but then it is not used at all in the xml. So basically the xml is in no namespace whereas according to the schema, the xml should be in the specific namespace `http://www.fixprotocol.org/FIXML-5-0-SP2`.
So either remove the alias:

```
<FIXML v="FIX.5.0SP2" xmlns="http://www.fixprotocol.org/FIXML-5-0-SP2">
```

Or use the alias in all element tags like this:

```
<xs:FIXML v="FIX.5.0SP2" xmlns:xs="http://www.fixprotocol.org/FIXML-5-0-SP2">
```